# Syntax Error in Angular App: Unexpected token <

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular app which runs perfectly in my local and production environment..
After a tiny change I made, I ran the app locally and it works fine.. Then I built the project and copied the *dist* folder to the web server. The problem is when I try to access to the app I get the following error in the Chrome Inspector:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < inline.1a152b6….bundle.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < polyfills.1553fdd….bundle.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < vendor.94d0113….bundle.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < main.d6f56a1….bundle.js:1
```

So, it seems like it is a misplaced character but in my local environment the app works fine I don't get any warning or error message on the console..

Comment: How do you build the app the last time? With the same options?

Comment: what does source control diff say

Comment: @Vega yep, ng build --prod --aot --deploy-url myApp --base-href myApp

Comment: Maybe your server has case sensitivity? Look for name changes in imports, names, etc... As Luke Hutton said, source control diff could be a help

Comment: If you have an improperly closed tag in the code higher up in the chain, then the first < the interpreter sees after that missing close tag will throw an error as it's still expecting a > on an earlier tag. So the error you're looking for is likely shortly before this point.

Comment: "After a tiny change I made". what change you made?

Comment: I just added a `routerLink` directive in a html file and maybe some changes in 2 or 3 files but I think those changes are irrelevant. The thing is maybe I add or deleted a character by mistake

Comment: I don't know why this is happening but the only thing I did was to clear my browser cache

Comment: In .NET core this was the only way to solve this issue: https://coderedirect.com/questions/443793/setting-up-angular-deep-linking-on-iis

Comment: **This solution works like a champ**  
1) Index.html file must have tag  <base href="/">. Add it in the top of the head section  

2)  Add URL rewrite in web config file. This file is available under dist folder once you build project using the command given in 3 point below.  

<action type="Rewrite" url="/" />  

3) ng build --prod --base-href ./

4) Paste dist folder build artifacts to application hosted directory.

It should work fine. It is working for me after struggling a lot on internet.

Comment: **ng build --prod --base-href ./** use this command for production deployment

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is most likely the result of a 404 page or a redirect to a page that serves regular html instead of the expected JavaScript files.
(A HTML page starts with `<html>` or a `<!DOCTYPE...>`)

Make sure that you have correctly uploaded the files and access the page correctly. You can verify by manually accessing the URL with the browser or look into the network tab of your browser development tools to inspect the response.

Comment: If I look into the network tab of my browser I can't see the index.html file.. Yet I still can see the *.js* files, but if I click on any of these files, the index code is showed in the preview tab.. @Thomas

Comment: That is exactly what I meant: You have a bad deployment or configuration that serves the index file when a JS file is requested. Assumption is that the deployment did not include the JS files and the index file is served in case a file is not found.

Comment: Ok, at least this is getting more sense to me now. But why is it that I can see those files on my *dist* folder and they seem to have their respectively code ?..

Comment: Your local files may be different from what has been copied to your webserver, it could be a caching issue as well. (Try clearing the browser cache)

Comment: I think I just solved it.. I had to modify the script paths and the base href attribute in the index file properly. So, instead of `base href="myApp"`, I changed to `href="/myApp"` and the same thing with the script paths

Comment: It looks like the 404, which causes the problem, is a consequence of using FallbackResource /index.html. FallbackResource looked nice but seems not to be able to replace mod_rewrite at the end.

Comment: @GerardoTarragona in my index.html it is already written`<base href="/">`. what could be other possible issue?

Comment: @Thomas i have this problem on iphone 8 only.why this specific behaviour?

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue:

1) I ran the command

```
ng build --aot --prod
```

2) Everything compiled without an error

3) I deleted all the files on the server and copied it all across via FTP(FileZilla) to a windows Azure server

4) Sometimes I get the error

```
Unexpected token <
```

and other-times not

Yesterday I noticed that the **main[hash].js** was missing on the server and that Filezilla did not give me an error copying it.

I then tried copying only that file.It did not work. When I removed the hash part from the filename it copies without a problem.

**Work-a-round**

**Run:**

```
ng  build --aot --prod --output-hashing none
```

Which works every-time.

So either Filezilla or Windows Server does not allow filenames with a specific length or it does not like certain hashes.

Comment: This fixed it for me.

Comment: delete hash is big problem for cache

Comment: this is exactly the issue I have, after seeing this, I noticed there are a few files in the fail to upload window. what's wrong with Filezilla?

Comment: Cache busting  not possible  delete the hash

Comment: building without output hashing shouldnot be encouraged . this question mentions importance of output hashing https://stackoverflow.com/q/55402751/20300178

Answer (score 9):

Got this error as well using angular with express.

I guess when you build an angular project the project is stored in '**dist/the-app**' not just '**dist**' so this solved my problem on express.

```
// Point static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/the-app')));
```

for me, this error was due to not setting the proper path of the built application.

Comment: The same thing happened in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is with the `<base href="/">` part of `index.html` file, it seems angular generates build file inside `dist/{yourProjectName}/` but the `index.html` files goes through the `dist/` for build files. Now you have 2 options:

1. Change the `<base href="/">` part of the `index.html` file to `<base href="/dist/{yourProjectName}/">` but now you have inconsistency between the `ng serve` command and `ng build` and you can't see your project through `ng serve`. So you have change that part every time!
2. The seccond approach that I recommend, is just changing the output path of the project!
   Go to your `angular.json` file of your project and change the `"outputPath": "dist/{yourProjcetName}",` to `"outputPath": "dist/"` and don't change the `base href`!

Answer (score 4):

I'm totally new to Angular so it may not help or at least seem obvious to a lot of you, but in my case it happened every time I reloaded a page that's not the root page, and it came from the fact that, in my `index.html` file, the base tag looked like this `<base href="./">`, I had to remove the . so it looks like this : `<base href="/">` .

Comment: worked for me too, except since my app was at 'apps/my-app' I had to specifiy `<base href="/apps/my-app/">`

Comment: Or use `ng build --base-href='/apps/my-app/'` Note: closing and ending "/" are important.

Comment: Does that **./** mean current directory and **/** mean root directory.

Answer (score 4):

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

add above lines to index.html

Reason: Chrome caches the index.html so the hash in main.hash.js does not get updated and we get the "unexpected token error <".

Comment: I added these headers using my .htaccess file. I can see that the headers are received the browser using the inspector. Despite this I still get this error whenever I update the app.
I assume this is because the hashes on my .js files change when the app is updated.
Can I do nothing about this error? Users see a white page and have to refresh the application.

Answer (score 4):

I solved by changing in `index.html`

```
<base href="/">
```

to

```
<base href=".">
```

or you can set the exact path to the folder that contains your index.html:

```
<base href="/path/to/index-folder">
```

Answer (score 3):

.NET Core solution if you use SpaStaticFile service collection extension and API project for example.

*Base href: /*

```
// ConfigureServices
// Correct RootPath to your angular app build, based on angular.json prop
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
    configuration.RootPath = "App/dist";
});

// Configure
// In order to serve files
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "App", "dist")),
    RequestPath = ""
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue.

In my case, the `main.bundle.js` was missing. Copying that file again to the `dist` folder solved the issue.

One more change that I did was to change the following in the `index.html` file in the dist -

```
<base href=".">
```

To

```
<base href="/">
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case was a mismatch route path in the server file. the route to statics must be the dir containing both the index.html and the assets dir, not the assets dir itself.

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,'/dist')));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(path.resolve(__dirname, '/dist/index.html')));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried below which is worked for me.

Here

The HTML `<base href="xyz"/>` specifies a base path for accessing relative URLs to assets such as images, scripts, and style sheets.

For example, given the `<base href="/myApp/">`, if your app wanted to access css file from the URL such as assets/css/styles.css, it will goes into a server request for myApp/assets/css/styles.css

I have deployed my angular build on Xampp server locally in below two way:

1. xampp -> htdocs -> "build files" (including assets, .htaccess, index.html, etc.)
2. xampp -> htdocs -> myApp -> "build files" (including assets, .htaccess, index.html, etc.)

For 1.

Now, I wanted my browser to access localhost:80/assets/css/styles.css, and here our assets folder is in root level, thus for access the css we have to put `<base href="./">` which access assets folder from root level.

URL Will goes to : localhost:80/assets/css/styles.css

For 2.

i wanted my browser to access localhost:80/myApp/assets/css/styles.css, so here our assets folder is in root level, thus for access the css we have to put `<base href="/myApp/">` which access assets folder from inside the myApp.

URL Will goes to : localhost:80/myApp/assets/css/styles.css

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the server, you are using.
For example with Apache, you set the **.htaccess** file to a relative path on your drive, where your app is located with `RewriteBase`. Also set the `<base href="">` accordingly.

With node, the

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
```

should go before `app.get`.

Check also, that the build had no errors and all files were copied to dist.

Answer (score 1):

I have a webapi project and angular, after trying different ways, following resolved the redirection issue for me

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        //For angular url rewriting
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
            {
                context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                await next();
            }
        })
        .UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions { DefaultFileNames = new List<string> { "index.html" } })
        .UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try change the base tag from `<base href="/">` to `<base href="/project-app/">` inside index.html file.

Answer (score 1):

node server : `server.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const pathDeploy = path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'oursurplus');
app.use(express.static(pth));

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`running on port ${port}`);
});

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(pathDeploy, 'index.html'));
});
```

`package.json` must have the script:

```
scripts: {
    "build": "ng build --prod --baseHref=\"./\""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience i'm add other assets to wwwroot is conflicted to detect static base address for asp.net core.

For example:

```
wwwroot
      |--> assets 
                  |---> ckeditor
```

Is conflict with `angular -> src -> assets` 
and show this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < inline.1a152b6….bundle.js:1
...
```

Comment: This is because there are two similar assets folders `wwwroot/assets/xxx` & `ClientApp\[Project]\assets` and read from `wwwroot/assets/xxx`
Choose another name for the server folder

Answer (score 0):

In my case the `<!--...-->` was the cause of the error

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more.

Comment: @Sergiu Starciuc Can you please explain?

Comment: This means that I removed some comment from a template file and it compiled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, very irritating. I tried several of the solutions found here, but none worked.

Adding the following in the Application Settings blade of the application in the Azure portal did the trick -

App Setting Name: WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION
Value: 6.9.1

>
Before and after - excerpts from the deployment log.

```
remote: The package.json file does not specify node.js engine version constraints.
remote: The node.js application will run with the default node.js version 0.10.40.
remote: Selected npm version 1.4.28


remote: The package.json file does not specify node.js engine version constraints.
remote: The node.js application will run with the default node.js version 6.9.1.
remote: Selected npm version 3.10.8
```

[image: screen capture from azure portal]

Answer (score 0):

With a little change in the `.htaccess` file i managed to fixed this problem.

I changed some lines from https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback to the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the result of incorrect input of UTF-8 characters.

Syntax was:

```
<component [inputField]="Artikelns Mått"></component>
```

First it was solved by just replacing the `å` with `a`. But, thats not really a solution.

What solved it was adding `''` around the text.

```
<component [inputField]="'Artikelns Mått'"></component>
```

Error:

```
Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token 'å' at column 11 in [Artikelns mått] in CadComponent@25:28 ("
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <lte-box>
            <lte-box-header [ERROR ->][headerTitle]="Artikelns mått"></lte-box-header>
            <lte-box-body>
                <table "): CadComponent@25:28
Parser Error: Lexer Error: Unexpected character [å] at column 12 in expression [Artikelns mått] at column 13 in [Artikelns mått] in CadComponent@25:28 ("
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <lte-box>
            <lte-box-header [ERROR ->][headerTitle]="Artikelns mått"></lte-box-header>
            <lte-box-body>
                <table "): CadComponent@25:28
    at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (webpack:///./@angular/compiler/src/facade/errors.js?:31:27) [<root>]
    at new SyntaxError (webpack:///./@angular/compiler/src/util.js?:163:16) [<root>]
    at TemplateParser.parse (webpack:///./@angular/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.js?:170:19) [<root>]
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (webpack:///./@angular/compiler/src/jit/compiler.js?:381:68) [<root>]
    at eval (webpack:///./@angular/compiler/src/jit/compiler.js?:264:62) [<root>]
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>) [<root>]
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (webpack:///./@angular/compiler/src/jit/compiler.js?:264:19) [<root>]
    at createResult (webpack:///./@angular/compiler/src/jit/compiler.js?:146:19) [<root>]
    at Zone.run (webpack:///./zone.js/dist/zone.js?:112:43) [<root> => <root>]
    at eval (webpack:///./zone.js/dist/zone.js?:534:57) [<root>]
    at Zone.runTask (webpack:///./zone.js/dist/zone.js?:150:47) [<root> => <root>]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (webpack:///./zone.js/dist/zone.js?:432:35) [<root>]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this to error to be a broad instance of many possible errors.  In our application that was using Jhipster generated project, We added google analytics in the index.html.  We also tried matomo analytics.  Inside the index.html we have script tags as well.

The error was that someone commented out a line of code in our google analytics snippet.

here is an example of the code where the error lived:

```html
<script>
        (function (b, o, i, l, e, r) {
            b.GoogleAnalyticsObject = l;
            b[l] || (b[l] =
                function () {
                    (b[l].q = b[l].q || []).push(arguments)
                });
            b[l].l = +new Date;
            e = o.createElement(i);
            r = o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
            e.src = '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(e, r)
        }(window, document, 'script', 'ga'));
        ga('create', '123123'); <! --
        ga('send', 'pageview');
        -->

    </script>
```

Notice the last three lines where there was `<! --`.  That cause the error for us.

In index.html script tag, to comment out a line we use `\\` double back slash.  Someone may have attempted to comment this line out using `<!-- -->` .

This is tricky cause it could have been anywhere.
But its always a good place to start in the `index.html`

Hope this helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and realized that I had changed the app.use(express.static(static folder)) statement after my last deploy causing this same `unexpected token <` error.

Make sure that your `app.use(express.static(static folder))` statement contains the appropriate static folder where your js and css files are located and relative to where you are running node.

If you are using Angular and precompiling (`ng build --prod`) your front-end Angular code into a dist folder containing these files and not putting your back-end node files in the same folder (e.g a separate backend), then you may need to include the correct path as well.

For my example, I have my precompiled (`ng build --prod`) Angular files in /dist right off the project directory.  Note that I also changed angular.json to be `"outputPath": "dist"` prior to precompiling to ensure this is where the precompiled Angular code would go.  My server.js file that just starts the node server is at the project root, but my app.js file that contains the `app.use(express.static(static folder))` statement and all the rest of my back-end node code is in a folder called /backend.  The following statements both work for me in this case to correctly find the js and css files and eliminate the `unexpected token <` error:

```
  app.use(express.static(path.join('dist')));
```

or

```
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../dist')));
```

Both statements appropriately direct node to look for the static js and css files in the `/dist` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the number of answers, this issue can show up for a host of reasons.

I'll add mine incase it helps others.  In my case, I was trying to directly hit a url that I wanted to forward back to index.html and let Angular handle it.

So if I went to `http://example.com/some-angular-route/12345`

In the network tab, I noticed that it was serving the scripts with the angular route in the url (`http://example.com/some-angular-route/runtime.js`)

Naturally, since nginx couldn't find `/some-angular-route/runtime.js`, it fell back to serve to index.html since I set `try_files` (in the nginx config) to test the $uri first and if couldn't find it, serve index.html.  So essentially:

- index.html has a script tag that tries to load `http://example.com/some-angular-route/runtime.js`
- fallback in nginx config serves index.html when it can't resolve the file
- contents of runtime.js are now same as index.html which starts with `<html>`
- Since that isn't valid js, you get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

So how do we get `/some-angular-route/` out of the url for `runtime.js`?  We have to make sure you have the [base-href](https://angular.io/guide/router#base-href) set to `/`.  You can do this from the cli with the flag `--base-href=/`

That flag will add  in your head tag of index.html and will force the browser to resolve all scripts from the root of the site. You can be on a url that includes `some-angular-route` but load a file like runtime.js (which is a relative url) from `/`.

Answer (score 0):

After ng build go to dist/your project folder say 'something'.  Then open the index.html file and change the base URL, which is  by default.

If you put your project folder on nginx or apache then tour base URL should be

```
<base href="http://localhost/something/">
```

and in my case, version of Angular is: 7.1.4

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue because I had generated the components but the routing was not proper or had not done with routing, so I think any of you gets this error first of all, check have you left something incomplete.

For me it was because of routing.

Answer (score 0):

the solution for me was:
in index.html

```
<base href="./">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem cause I had used **--base-href** and **--deploy-url** with same parameters. like this:

```
ng build --base-href /spo/ --deploy-url /spo/
```

When I removed **--deploy-url** flag everything start to working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, if you are modifying the index.html file deployed in the host server, you must save the encoding of the file to UTF-8 so that it will load the page as is

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the HTML was inside the single quotes and it has multiple lines in the template.

so I just provided the HTML inside the backtick character (`) in place of the single quote (')

Answer (score -1):

Just add after of `/` the folder name of you project just like said [Gerardo Tarragona](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2621320/gerardo-tarragona).

Example:

```
/myProject
```

Regards

Answer (score -1):

For a quick workaround though (WHICH IS DEFINITELY NOT RECOMMENDED AND NOT A GOOD PRACTICE) you can build in non prod mode. Try `ng build` only.

Comment: --prod has now been deprecated. ng build will build in production mode by default. Instead use ng build --configuration development

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same problem a couple of times, I solved it this way:

Build the project with a user other than root (ubuntu - normaluser)

```
root$ chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu my-project-folder/
ubuntu$ cd my-project-folder/
ubuntu$ npm install 
ubuntu$ ng build -xxx params xx etc
```

In production server show nginx user :

```
root$ grep -rh user /etc/nginx/*
user www-data; # in my case
```

Now move or replace my-project-folder

```
root$ mv my-project-folder/ /var/www/awesome.com
```

And change permissions to nginx user

```
root$ chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/awesome.com
```

(Y)

Answer (score -1):

in your `index.ts` change

```
<!--doctype html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

remember... **The <!DOCTYPE> declaration is NOT case sensitive.**
check the following [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1**: Build Project with following command [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50483825/3411787):

```
ng  build --aot --prod --output-hashing none
```

**Step 2**: Add dist folder to code versioning/on server

```
git add /dist/* -f
```

**Step 3**: Checkout build on server and try to refresh page.

Answer (score -1):

For me, the problem cause was permissions of the `/assets` directory after copying the files genrated in `/dist/*` to the production machine. The `/assets` directory was copied over, but upon copying, the permissions on it were being set like this:

```
drwx------  4 admin admin    4096 Feb 21 08:58 assets/
```

I needed to `chmod -R a+rx assets` to get it to look like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 admin admin    4096 Feb 21 08:58 assets/
```

And then everything worked perfectly because the web server user could access files in the directory.

The problem here is that (as other people on this question have stated) the problem is really a "file not found" error that's returning a `200` status code. So the browser is requesting a file in `/assets`, `layout-helpers.js` in my case, not finding it, and returning the contents of `index.html`, which the browser then tries to interpret as a JavaScript file, resulting in the contents being returned not being valid JavaScript.

The problem was visible in the web server error logs.  It's just be the last I would look for what seems like a JavaScript error, so I wasted a good amount of time looking elsewhere.

Fixing the directory permissions fixed everything.

This was my resolution, hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score -3):

In my case, I just had to do a 'hard refresh' of the page to clear its cache (using Chrome under Linux it's done by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>). After that, everything worked fine again.

Cheers,