# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < using angular 4 build run in browser

Tags: angular

I am facing error when I upload new build on browser and if anybody loggedin than coming error

> inline.57a333035d837818438d.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>   polyfills.5f6d6a7d7feb0c3e5505.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>   scripts.6c8a1a10135e42d14585.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>   vendor.b3c0b3ee753b8f03095a.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>   main.efdf2f2159c67438cfe2.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Any one can tell me,

Thanks

Comment: did you take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222464/syntax-error-in-angular-app-unexpected-token ?

Comment: Most likely you have an extra < before the tag.

Comment: where i can check and  resolve the issue

Comment: What server are you using to serve the generated folder?

Answer (score 1):

After `ng build` check your dist folder if the directory is `dist/projectname`
modify `server.js` or `app.js` to use the below code.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/projectname/')));
app.listen(port);
app.get("*", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/dist/projectname/"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case, the Angular version 16 that we were using wasn't compatible to the browser that we were testing it in.

Things we did:

- Check our site in an old Chrome version - use Browserstack
- Utilize the browserslist - use this `ng generate config browserslist`

And, added this

```
Chrome >=60
Firefox >=63
Edge >=79
Safari >=13
iOS >=13
```

Answer (score -1):

in your `index.ts` change

```
<!--doctype html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

because **The <!DOCTYPE> declaration is NOT case sensitive.**
check the following [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)