# Angular 4 app in nginx unable to load file

Tags: angular, ubuntu, nginx

I have deployed angular 4 app using nginx. But its unable to load js,css and other files. I see these error in console

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <     inline.bundle.js:1
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <     polyfills.bundle.js:1
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <     scripts.bundle.js:1
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined at styles.bundle.js:1 styles.bundle.js:1
>   (anonymous) @ styles.bundle.js:1
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <       vendor.bundle.js:1
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
>       at main.bundle.js:1 main.bundle.js:1

My nginx configuration:

```
 server {
     listen 80 default_server;
     listen [::]:80 default_server;


     root /var/www/html;

     # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
     index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

     server_name _;
      location / {
             # First attempt to serve request as file, then
             # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
             #alias /web-portal/;

             root /var/www/html/web-portal/;
             try_files  $uri$args $uri$args/  /index.html =404;
     }

 }
```

Kindly Help Me to solve This !!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a duplicate of "[Syntax Error in Angular App: Unexpected token <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222464/syntax-error-in-angular-app-unexpected-token)".

Please check (and/or share us) your `base href` attribute in your project.

It could be related to your issue.

Comment: <base href="./">