# Not able to render static html of Angular build from node

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular

I wanted to render the static files of Angular from my node server.

As an experiment, Below are the steps i took:

Created a dist folder by building my Angular project using

```
ng build --prod
```

Copied the `dist` folder to the root directory of my node server

Configured express app in my node server to point to index.html of `dist` folder. Below are the snips of configuration code i wrote -

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../front-end/dist/')))

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
 return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../front-end/dist/my-first-app/index.html'))
})
```

When i run my node server locally on port 3000 If i am correct, it should get redirected to index.html page within the compiled angular `dist` folder. Well, i see the redirection attempt being made by node. However, after redirection the browser is failing to load the html within the index.html file. It throws the below error on the console-

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

The above error tells clearly that the browser failed to load the html page. I believe my understanding is correct. But i am not able to figure out why this error gets logged. I hope i get some answers here.

I am trying to work without Angular CLI's `ng serve` command. If i succeed, i will try to attempt this on cloud. My intension is i want to make use of only static files generated out of Angular build rather than loading them using `ng serve` and also to render these files on browser from a call using node. Since back-end server has to be the only running server and frontend should not be a server but rather simple static files which needs to be served with data from the former. I hope i made sense.

Comment: Did you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222464/syntax-error-in-angular-app-unexpected-token)?

Comment: @GCSDC I missed that question. It was very useful and i got my solution though. Thank you very much. The issue with my code was, i missed a sub directory of my build directory path. I modified my code like this and it worked - `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../front-end/dist/my-first-app')))` So basically, i had missed to specify `my-first-app` which had all the build files

Answer (score 0):

Try to serve the static files directly with a path, e.g. `/` and run the app on a port

```
app.use('/', express.static('pathToAngular/'));
app.listen(3000);
```

Then your static files, also the angular created javascript files will be served under the local adress

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

To let the angular generated javascript/html files know about their *location* (deploy url), make sure you add the `deployUrl` key in your **angular.json** file

```
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    "optimization": true,
    [...]
    "deployUrl": "http://localhost:3000/",
    "baseHref": "./"
  }
}
```

Don't forget the slash at the end and also add the `baseHref` entry. In general you'll want to create another configuration with the nodejs local deploy url and add the production server url in the `production` configuration.

Comment: Thank you. I will try your solution. Also could you please share a simple demo of what you explained above?